# Can this be Combinatorial proof for $n2^{n-1}$ = $\sum_{k=0}^{n}k {n \choose k}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, binomial-theorem

Would this approach be counted as a combinatorial proof? Or is it just a normal proof??

**My Approach**

From Binomial Theorem

$(x+a)^{n}$ = $\sum_{k=1}^{n} {a^{n-k}}{x^k}{n \choose k}$
 Let’s say a=1.

∴$(x+1)^{n}$ = $\sum_{k=1}^{n} {1^{n-k}}{x^k}{n \choose k}$

$(x+1)^{n}$ = $\sum_{k=1}^{n} {x^k}{n \choose k}$

Taking the Derivative w.r.t x on both sides,

$n(x+1)^{n-1}$ = $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k{x^{k-1}} {n \choose k}$

From this, we can say that for all values of x, the above equation is true.
Let’s say x=1

∴$n(1+1)^{n-1}$ = $\sum_{k=0}^{n}k {n \choose k}$

∴$n2^{n-1}$ = $\sum_{k=0}^{n}k {n \choose k}$'

**Aproach 2**

Firstly, we pick a team of k people from the n members available, then choose one of the k members of team to be the Captain. There are ${n \choose k}$ combinations to choose a team of k people, after which there are $k$ options for the captain. As there are different cases .  So, we have $\sum_{k=1}^n {n \choose k}k$.

On the other hand, we could first pick one person from the $n$ people to be the captain.  Then for each of the remaining unchosen $n-1$ people, they can be either in or out of the team.  That's $2^{n-1}$ possibilities.  So, we have $n2^{n-1}$.

Comment: Definitely doesn’t seem like a combinatorial proof.

Comment: In a combinatorial proof, you count something.  There is no counting here, so it's not combinatorial.

Comment: **Hint:** Try counting the number of ways in which you line up balls where there is a single gold ball and the rest are blue and/or red.

Comment: This is an algebraic proof.

Comment: Count the number of ways of choosing a team and a leader for the team. If the team has $k$ members, this can be done in $k\binom{n}{k}$ ways. This gives the right hand side. Now choose the team leader first. This can be done in $n$ ways. Choose a team from the remaining $n-1$ members. This can be done in $2^{n-1}$ ways. This gives the left hand side.

Comment: I updated the post, with a different approach can you confirm if this way can be counted as a combinatorial proof??